# Create EKS kubernetes pod in specific subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-cloudformation, subnet, amazon-eks

I am creating 11 pods on EKS kubernetes. I have two public and two private subnets.
In that, I have to move 10 pods in private subnet and 1 pod in public subnet. The reason behind moving in a public subnet is I have to attach public facing load balancer IP to it. But I have not sure how to move particular pod in particular subnet on EKS. I got similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54027386/eks-in-private-subnet-load-balancer-in-public-subnet). But. didn't got answer.
All things I am creating via Cloudformation.
How can I create particular pod in particular subnet on EKS?

Comment: Dennis Griesert's answer can fix issue. When node has network internface only in private subnets or public subnets.

If my nodes have both public subnet and private subnet. How can I specific pod to private subnets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [Kubernetes' nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) is the thing you need. You just have to add a fitting label to the nodes, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52228629/10761013) will help you automate it.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. But how can attach a label to individual worker nodes. The link you provided attaching same label to all worker nodes. But I want attach label like if nodes in public subnet, I want to attach public label, if in private subnet , attach private as label.

Comment: You can get instance metadata as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html). Just add what reference you deem necessary (e.g. the subnet) to the user-data running on the instances.